# Rspec -- How to test method by calling it and checking for change in object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I am learning how to write tests so I'm writing one for a small method that I wrote. I want to call this method, `update_user_region_id`, and I should be expecting a change in the `user` object.

```
def update_user_region_id(user_id, region_id)
  user = User.where(id: user_id).first
  region = Region.where(id: region_id).first
  return if user.nil?
  user.region_id = region_id
  user.region = region.name
  user.save!
end
```

`update_user_region_id` is a method called from another method (not sure if this is relevant).

For my test, I've written:

```
it 'should update user region id' do
  user = Factory :user
  city = Factory :city
  expect{
    update_user_region_id(user.id, city.id)
  }.to change(user, :region_id)
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `update_user_region_id' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007f9e0a57f490>
```

**1. Is this a good test?**

**2. How do I fix this test?**

Thanks.

Comment: In which class is the `update_user_region_id ` method defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the context in which you call it, `self` refers to an object of class `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1`, and since you don't provide an explicit receiver, it's that `self` object that receives the message.

As @pjam notes, without more information it's impossible to explain how exactly to fix your test. But the general point is that the `update_user_region_id` message needs an appropriate receiver. If, for example, that were a class method on the `Foo` class, you could call `Foo.update_user_region_id`. Or if it's an instance method, you may need to instantiate an object first (e.g., `Foo.new.update_user_region_id`).